# Para que serve aquele "sr-only" do Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Estudando a documentação fiquei com dúvidas: para que realmente serve a classe [`sr-only`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-screen-readers) do bootstrap?

Comment: Essa pergunta já existe no Stack Overflow em Inglês, dê uma olhada ai: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758598/what-is-sr-only-in-bootstrap-3 ele serve praticamente pra esconder informações usadas por leitores de tela....

Answer (score 10):

A documentação diz:

> Hide an element to all devices except screen readers

Ou seja:

> Esconde um elemento para todos os dispositivos, exceto leitores de tela.

Portanto, é uma maneira de apresentar conteúdos que só são considerados por leitores de tela (que são browsers que lêem o conteúdo para quem não enxerga).

Answer (score 3):

De acordo com a [documentação do Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-screen-readers), essa classe serve para ocultar sessões da sua página exceto em leitores de tela.

Ela é usada para questões de acessibilidade, nesse caso mais especificamente voltado para deficiência visual. É algo parecido como o atributo `alt` de tags de imagem.

Mais informações sobre [acessibilidade para deficientes visuais](http://www.brasilmedia.com/Cegueira.html).

Comment: Exatamente como na resposta do [S.O](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758598/what-is-sr-only-in-bootstrap-3)